# Using the Django ORM to join on the same table

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, orm

I am currently switching our server from Java to Python (Django) and am using the ORM to recreate our SQL queries, one of them is proving difficult as I need to join on the same table. Below is the query

```
SELECT  U1.suser, COUNT(U1.id) FROM United U1 INNER JOIN United U2 ON 
U1.sUser = U2.pUser WHERE U2.sUser IN (select sUser from united where pUser = '105660') 
and U1.pUser = '105660' and U1.sUser IN ('580664','1015396') GROUP BY U1.id, U1.suser
```

This is my model:

```
class United(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
puser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='puser')
suser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='suser',
                          related_name='secondary_united')
date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=34, blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'United'
    unique_together = (('puser', 'suser'),)
```

the query is meant to find the number of mutual connections between myself (the calling user) and all of their friends (the list of ID's)

The query works how I want it to using straight SQL (although I cannot get it to work using the .raw() method because of this primary key error

```
django.db.models.query_utils.InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key
```

but I would like to find a way to do it using the ORM.

Comment: Sorry @e4c5 added in the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you attempted to invoke the query as

```
United.objects.raw(sql)
```

That would indeed produce an error as you mention because your projection `U1.suser, COUNT(U1.id)` does not have an id column it. You would need to change it to something like this

```
SELECT U1.id, U1.suser, COUNT(U1.id) FROM United U1 INNER JOIN United U2 ON 
U1.sUser = U2.pUser WHERE U2.sUser IN (select sUser from united where pUser = '105660') 
and U1.pUser = '105660' and U1.sUser IN ('580664','1015396') GROUP BY U1.id, U1.suser
```

note that it has to be `U1.id` and not `U2.id` because you are grouping on `U1.id`

Admittedly this query would be a bit hard to write using the ORM. Owing to the fact that you are joining United to itself and django ORM joins are usually only through foreign keys or many to many fields only.

Comment: Ok that worked... As I thought it would cause I was almost positive I had tried it with U1.id in the select fields, but I guess i didn't.
Thank you!

Comment: There we go! Upvoted and Checked as accepted answer.